# C. Error: Duplicated function definition. What could be cause of this?

Tags: c

I am a beginner programmer and I am writing simple implementation of the game "Snake" in C language and using SDL2 library.
Everything was going well until I decided to separate the code into separate files and functions. Now when I am trying to compile my project there’s an error:

`Snake/src\snake.c:8: duplicated definition «init_snake»;`
`CMakeFiles\Snake.dir/objects.a(main.c.obj):Snake/src\..\src\snake.c:8: first definition`

I was confused that the first definition of a function and its redefinition were on the same line of a single file. I searched the whole project with IDE and found only two places where the function "init_snake" occurs. In fact, that’s her definition and the location of the call. After my Google search, I found information that I did wrong with the initialization of the variables in the header files. Like this:

```
const static int SIZE = 10;
```

For the sake of interest, I removed the variables from the header files and decided to test without them (although I felt that this would not help, because in the error was a function, not a variable).
And it really didn’t help.

To be sure, I decided to search for the information about includes. To avoid crossing of the code, I added #include guard (found on the Internet) and `#pragma once`. Although it did not help with this error, but the thing is cool (if I understood correctly how it works).

So I came here to ask the experts for advice. What’s going on? Because I define a function in one single place, and then I call it once from another place.

Below I apply the current version of the code.

main.c

```C++
#include "../include/main.h"

#include "../src/snake.c"

int
main(int argc,
     char *args[])
{
    SDL_Window *window = NULL;
    window = SDL_CreateWindow("Snake",
                              SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                              SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                              525,
                              525,
                              SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    if (NULL == window)
    {
        printf("Window was not created. Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        exit(1);
    }

    SDL_Renderer *renderer = NULL;
    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window,
                                  -1,
                                  SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
    if (NULL == renderer)
    {
        printf("Renderer was not created. Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        exit(1);
    }

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xFF);
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

    init_snake(renderer, 525 / 2, 525 / 2, 16);

    bool quit = false;
    SDL_Event e;
    while (!quit)
    {
        //Handle events on queue
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&e) != 0)
        {
            if (e.type == SDL_QUIT)
            {
                quit = true;
            }
        }
    }

    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

main.h

```C++
#pragma once
#ifndef MAIN_H
#define MAIN_H

#include "SDL2/SDL.h"

#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#endif
```

snake.c

```C++
#include "../include/snake.h"

void
init_snake(SDL_Renderer *renderer,
           int x,
           int y,
           int length)
{
    assert(renderer);

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        SDL_Rect rect;
        rect.x = x;
        rect.y = y;
        rect.w = 12;
        rect.h = 10;
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0x0, 0xFF, 0x0, 0xFF);
        SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &rect);
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    }
}
```

snake.h

```C
#pragma once
#ifndef SNAKE_H
#define SNAKE_H
    
#include "SDL2/SDL.h"

#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
    
#endif
```

Please let me know if I have done anything wrong in creating of this question - I will try to fix it. If you need any additional information, please let me know and I will clarify.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: `#include "../src/snake.c"` from `main.c` looks like an error.

Comment: Hello, jxh!
To be honest, I didn’t know that I can't include .c files. Is that the only problem? I just have to do the include only .h files?

Comment: Only include the header file. The way you work with multiple source files is that you link them together during the linking stage of your build.

Comment: Thank you, gentlemen! The program works! It creates a window, and even draws a green rectangle! I’m so glad! Thank you so much, it is a good lesson for me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no rule in the C standard or compilers generally that you cannot include `.c` files. But there is a convention for how we name and use files:

Files with names ending in `.c` contain *definitions* of objects and/or functions. For objects, definitions are declarations written so that they cause storage to be reserved (like external definitions with initializations, such as `int MyFoo = 0;`, although we generally avoid externally visible objects these days). For functions, definitions are declarations that include the body of the function (the code that it executes).

Files with names ending in `.h` contain *declarations* of objects and/or functions that are not definitions. These declarations merely describe the object or function without defining it. For objects, `extern int MyFoo;` is a declaration that describes but does not define `MyFoo`. For a function `extern int bar(double x);` is a declaration that does not define `bar`. The `extern` is default for a function, so you can leave it off and write `int bar(double x);`.

Given a file name such as `MyModuleX`, we commonly use the file `MyModuleX.c` to define the objects and functions of `MyModuleX`, and we use the file `MyModuleX.h` to tell other parts of the program about the objects and functions that `MyModuleX` provides.

So every source file that uses things from `MyModuleX` should have `#include "MyModuleX.h"`. Also, `MyModuleX.c` should also have that, so the compiler sees the declarations and the definitions at the same time and can check that they match. No file should have `#include "MyModuleX.c"`, because we do not get functions into the program by including source files. Instead, we compile each source file separately (possibly in one command, but the compiler will compiler them individually) and link them together.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! Something has come clear.

Answer (score 1):

If you include `snake.c`, that means that its code will be included twice when compiling. Using `#include` on a file just literally inserts all the code in your file. Meaning, when compilation happens, `main.c` contains all of `snake.c`, and since you're also compiling `snake.c`, everything you define in it will be defined twice. So, you'll have to not include `snake.c` in `main.c`. Just include its header file. And in the header file, pre-define any functions that you want to use elsewhere, so you don't have to include the whole C file in order to have access to those functions.

Comment: The program works! It creates a window, and even draws a green rectangle! I’m so glad! Thank you so much!